# Formal obligation letter or family member?

Tags: usa, schengen, germany, paperwork

I am applying for a Schengen visa from the United States with Germany entry. My relative is a student in Germany and is not a German either.

I was wondering if I should tell him to write an invitation letter or should I do a formal obligation letter? Also, I do not know how to write a formal obligation. Is it something I can get at the consulate or should I do it prior to the interview?

Here are the requirements:

- Recent, informal signed invitation letter, passport copy and photocopy of residence permit if applicable from the host in Germany OR a formal obligation letter (Verpflichtungserklärung), notarized by an alien's authority in Germany and one copy.

Comment: As your relative is a student, do they have the resources to commit to a formal obligation agreement, and can they demonstrate those resources?  Its pointless submitting one if the immigration official considers it worthless...

Comment: I don't think he can when he is not a citizen there I just don't understand so whoever does not have a german relative what would they do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Germany this formal obligation is called a [Verpflichtungserklärung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verpflichtungserkl%C3%A4rung_(Ausl%C3%A4nderrecht)) and it is a promise to reimburse the state for any cost if you should overstay. It **must** be filed with the municipal authorities, and they will check if your relative has the means to pay for you. They might also require a deposit if that ability to pay is in question, but the liability would not be limited to that deposit.

Such an obligation may be filed by a person or company. Citizenship is not the issue, it depends on the ability to pay. Generally the person giving the Verpflichtungserklärung has to be able to pay a minimum livelihood for himself, his other dependents, and the recipients of the obligation. The exact amount varies from place to place to account for costs of living.